# Is a service worker cache faster than http cache?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

The test page has static JavaScript, CSS, images, etc. which are stored in a CDN with cache-control max-age set to about 5 years. We collect `load` events for the user to open the page and the average is about 1.9s. When I add a service worker cache and have it only cache the JavaScript, CSS, and images, the average `load` time is about 1.6s.

Why can a service worker cache reduce the page load time?

Comment: How are you setting up your tests and collecting the data?

Comment: Separately: Even 1.6s is a long page-load time. Have you already done the usual things to reduce it? (Minimizing HTTP requests, etc.?)

Comment: [This line](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache-objects) from the spec would seem to answer the question, depending on how you're measuring: *"The Cache objects do not expire unless authors delete the entries."* Your other resources may well be getting pushed out of the browser cache.

Comment: it's a ABTest for and online page,  and the metrics is Avg. Page Load Time. How to verify your assumption that other resources may well be getting pushed out of the browser cache.

Comment: service workers are supported on the latest browsers. Might be that the users that can take advantage from this tech just have faster devices which causes test results to be skewed.

Comment: *"it's a ABTest for and online page"* Are you referring to some specific tool, or just A/B testing as a concept? If not a specific tool, then again, how **specifically** are the results generated/calculated?

Comment: *"How to verify your assumption..."* Well, it's a hypothesis, not an assumpion. :-) The answer will depend on your answer to my first question. If you're doing this in the wild with real users, one option would be to use different URLs for the service-worker-cached content and the browser-cached content and see if browser-cached is getting downloaded more often relative to the main page (which I assume is uncacheable).

Comment: @marzelin - Wow, that's an interesting thought...

Comment: do you have the same results (sw cache faster) when testing the page manually?

Comment: @marzelin;@T.J. Crowder yeah, this test is in the wild with real users. and I also collect the browsers which not support service worker，you can exclude the effect of this.

Comment: @marzelin in my chrome devtool, sw cache slower

Answer (score 1):

Service worker can cache html files. Storing html files in a http cache is not a good idea (because there'd be virtually no way to update your site before cache expiration date)

also if you use `etags/If-None-Match`, the request is sent to check if the file changed before it is used.

Comment: my test is used to test the service worker cache between http cache, will not to cache the html.